# How to fix 'htaccess redirect entire site to maintenace, except one IP'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect an entire site to a maintenance page while I do some work on it. I want my IP to be the only one to view the site. I've tried

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.456.789
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

And this is my latest ( I need to allow one .png image)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=200.300,70.9
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rebrand-underway\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rebrand-underway.html [R=302,L]
```

This code is kind of working, as its redirecting properly. However I can't access the actual site from my ip address. So I suspect the IP I'm putting in the code is wrong, but I've tried every one I can find googling 'whats my ip', and through network settings on my computer, but nothing works.

Does anyone have any ideas? If I'm right, how might I find the correct IP?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using a valid IP address (both the IPs above are obviously invalid and the second one even includes a comma), then it would seem you are somehow using the wrong IP address, as the directives you've posted look OK. To clarify, where is this site hosted, and where are you accessing it from?

Comment: So check your http server's access log to find out the actual address your requests are coming from.

Comment: Apart from that you apparently need to take another look at how regular expressions work. You certainly do not really want to look for "123.456.789". Probably something like "^123\.456\.789"...

Comment: And to answer your question: the equals sign makes no sense there. The condition should be:  `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789` or similar.

Comment: @arkascha "the equals sign makes no sense there." - the equals _operator_ makes perfect sense here for allowing (with a _negated_ expression) a _specific_ IP address.

Comment: I do have to apologize. As @MrWhite correctly pointed out the equal operator can be used to compare a literal string instead of interpreting it as a regular expression as usually done by the rewriting module. My fault, I learned something today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It can be set as below for IP :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
```

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry its been a while since I've been on :)